# Is representativeness a necessary condition for generalisability?

Tags: sampling

If a large sample of volunteers were not representative of a specific population, would it necessarily mean that any conclusion of a study performed with sound methodology on this sample could not be generalized to that population?

Comment: What exactly does "representativeness" mean for you here?

Comment: No bias in selecting subjects. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16848/27782

Comment: No - but it means that the generalization is justified only by domain knowledge, not by statistics.

Comment: If the sample was really large, for example if it included a good majority of the population, you could start to claim the sample represented the population, absent strong reason to think otherwise.  So, what do you mean by large and how strong is the evidence that the sample is not representative?